# Author on birkjour class

Tags: article, addresses, author

I am writing an article on birkjour class (it can be found on http://www.springer.com/birkhauser?SGWID=0-40290-2-464809-0). We are two authors from the same university, so the address is the same for both of us. However, when I try to use \address it only works for one author, so basically I have to write the same thing twice, and on the PDF it appears twice. Is there any way to put it only once?

Comment: To write it only once, or have it appear only once in the PDF? If the latter, I just wouldn't bother about it, and have it twice. The journal/publisher decides the layout anyway. Each author has his own block with info anyway.